# How to put 2 condition in one statement actiolistener in java?

Tags: java, netbeans

Im trying to put two condition where the users pick selection in radiobutton "r1" and combobox "wdr1" and i want it to display picture output. But it didnt produce any output since the program can run it. Any suggestion to fix this?

```
if("r1".equals(combo2.getSelectedItem().equals("wdr1"))){

                icon1 = new ImageIcon("adidas.jpg");
                pic1.setIcon(icon1);
            }
```

Comment: `combo2.getSelectedItem().equals("wdr1")` is a boolean, and you are checking if "r1" (a string) is equal to it.
What is it that you are really trying to check?

Comment: oh  i thought r1 will be equal to combo2 if combo2 get pick, but if i used logical operator still didnt come out:                                                       if("r1".equals("White") || combo2.getSelectedItem().equals("wdr1"))){
            icon1 = new ImageIcon("adidas.jpg");
            pic1.setIcon(icon1);
        }

Comment: Now you have one too many or the `)` symbols. Also just be aware that you are using the OR operator and not AND. If you need both conditions to be met, you && instead of ||.